# How to see if a player got a specific tools in ROBLOX

Tags: lua, roblox

I am working for a Airport in Roblox and I need a script that when I click on a button, the script check if I have a specific tools in my inventory (In this case a suitcase). If I got the suitcase, the player who click on the button get the suitcase removed from his inventory. I don't want that the entire inventory get removed, only the tool. I want also that the suitcase respawn on a specific place. (On the conveyor.(Please, use X,Y,Z to respawning the suitcase)) I know this isn't a easy script but if someone know how to do it, I will be really happy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see this link for how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is check if the suitcase is `nil`, which is simple:

```
local suitcase = player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Suitcase")
if suitcase == nil then
--suitcase is nil!
else
--suitcase is not nil!
end
```

I used the `FindFirstChild()` function, which finds the first child of whatever's calling it specified, to see if the suitcase was `nil` or not. If there is no such child parented to the caller, `FindFirstChild()` returns `nil`.